# Failed to install MySQL 5.5.25-1 source package on RedHat

Tags: mysql, rpm, gperf

I'm trying to install MySQL-5.5.25-1.linux2.6.src.rpm package on RedHat machine, but error occurs when doing rpmbuild.

It prompts that gperf is needed, but I already have gperf 3.0.4 installed.

What should I do to solve this problem?

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -ivh MySQL-5.5.25-1.linux2.6.src.rpm 
  1:MySQL                  warning: user pb2user does not exist - using root
########################################### [100%]
warning: user pb2user does not exist - using root

[root@localhost /]# cd /usr/src
[root@localhost src]# cd redhat
[root@localhost redhat]# cd SPECS
[root@localhost SPECS]# ls
mysql.5.5.25.spec
[root@localhost SPECS]# rpmbuild -bp mysql.5.5.25.spec 
error: Failed build dependencies:
    gperf is needed by MySQL-5.5.25-1.linux2.6.i386
[root@localhost SPECS]# gperf --version
GNU gperf 3.0.4
Copyright (C) 1989-1998, 2000-2004, 2006-2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Written by Douglas C. Schmidt and Bruno Haible.
```

Answer (score 0):

Was your gperf installed as RPM or built?

If it is an RPM, try rebuilding the RPM database using rpm --rebuilddb.